# Count all the characters including spaces in linux

Tags: linux, unix

Can someone tell me if there is a way to count all the characters in a file including spaces?

I am using `wc -c <filename>` but it does not count `spaces` and `ctrlM` characters

Comment: weird... `wc -c` count bytes... should count spaces too (and newlines, tabs, etc.). And it does so here.

Comment: `echo "a b c d" | wc -c` -> `8`... Looks to me like it's counting the spaces and the terminating new line... How are you determining that it "does not count spaces and ctrlM characters"?

Comment: looks like had a file format issue, it was having trailing spaces that and characters. All set now.

Answer (score 2):

`wc -c` is what you need it does count the whitespace characters.

If you are having a different result please share the file, and output.